# Django static files urls setting

Tags: python, django

Please help me check my `static` setting

when `Debug =False`,it works well
But when `Debug=True`,It can't catch the static files

Please help me, Thank you.

Here is my settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('core.urls', namespace='core')),
)
if settings.DEBUG is False:    
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
            url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
else:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: There is no need for an else statement. In Debug mode static files should be served automatically.

Comment: I delete the else part,but still not work

Comment: as @pad said debug mode static files serve automatically .. Did you have `middleware class` listed in `settings.py` file

Answer (score 0):

If you will write the below code in urls.py it will work for both the DEBUG status

```
url( r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT } ),
```

and one thing to be noted my static root is like for django 1.4+

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname( __file__ ))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
```

along with this you need to do the following command to copy all static files to PROJECT_PATH/static dir

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```